# How to Create html table like structure using fabric js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[image: vertablo schema builder image]

I am trying to build schema builder similar to vertabelo. I'm using fabric.js for interactions. How can i create html table like structure where i can add columns and their types as shown in the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Html Table inside svg as shown below and convert it into image and use it as fabric object

```
var svgData = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">' +
           '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
           '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:30px">' +
             '<table border="1"><thead><tr><td>Title</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Id</td><td>char</td></tr></tbody></table>' + 
           '</div>' +
           '</foreignObject>' +
           '</svg>';

    // creating image from svg
    const dataUri = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(svgData)}`;
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: 300,  
            height: 200,  
        });

        canvas.add(imgInstance);
        canvas.renderAll();
    };
    img.src = dataUri;
```

Comment: How to interact with table row in fabric js